# GeoMyWP fields IF statement

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, isset, geo

Using the GeoMyWP plugin and need to create a statement to echo the content of a field only if that field has been filled in.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gmw_post_info info="website"]'); ?>
```

the above snippet displays the information stored in the 'website' field, but what I need to do is first check that field, see if anything is stored in it and if so display that data, but if not then do nothing. (that snippet itself produces nothing if the field is blank, but my layout requires headings for each and i don't want those headings to display if there is nothing to display)

my attempt is below, but unsuccessful.

```
<?php if ( isset( $gmw['website'] ) && !empty( $gmw['website'] ) ) { ?>
   Website: <?php echo do_shortcode('[gmw_post_info info="website"]'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

got it working by setting a variable to equal the required shortcode and echoing my desired content if not empty:

```
<?php
$website = do_shortcode('[gmw_post_info info="website"]');
if ($website != ""):
    echo "Website: ";
    echo $website; 
endif;
?>
```